# AS2 ID and URL in BizTalk Server 2009

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009, edifact

I am new to BizTalk and have some very basic understanding of what it does. My client wants to send and receive EDIFACT files over AS2 protocol and they have asked for our AS2 ID, AS2 URL and certificate (public if I am right). Please find my understanding below about these and correct me if anything goes wrong

1. AS2 ID - Not sure where and how to create AS2 ID in BizTalk 2009
2. AS2 URL - I have created a virtual directory[AS2] in IIS to receive files from client [Path mapped to C:\Program Files\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2009\HttpReceive] and the URL obtained is http:\ip_addr\as2
3. Certificate - Certificate is generated with 1 year validity using Certificate authority services in windows server 2003 and exported with [Do not export private key] option

Is the above AS2 URL correct to share with the client?

Is the certificate generated is valid to share?

And please tell me how to create AS2 ID

### Platform details:

Windows Server 2003
BizTalk 2009 with SQL Server 2005 Standard Edition [SP2]

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please see this Microsoft link:
[Configuring Identifiers (AS2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629698.aspx)

Your AS2 identifier is something you arbitrarily make up and then assign it to your partner agreements (Think TO:/From: Identifiers in addition to standard EDI envelopes)

As long as the certificate is your public key, it should be okay to share.  Most people generate a self-signed user certificate and exchange that with their partner.

That URL should be fine, and you should be able to test it from the outside.

Comment: Hi Andrew,  Thanks for your response. I referred to the article you suggested and found no options mentioned in that in BizTalk 2009 w.r.t AS2 [To my knowledge, most msdn article only focuses on BizTalk 2010 and most 2009 article pages says "Content not found"].  From your suggestion, I take it as AS2 identifier is not mandatory as we are using public key certificate for signing.  And last is, Will BizTalk throw an error to the sender if sender is signing the AS2 message and party is not configured with the sender public certificate?  You response is well appreciated

Comment: AS2 identifier is certainly mandatatory.  These identifiers are found in the MIME headers that get sent with the transmission.  I'm not sure how you got the impression you didn't need them.  My point was you can make yours up and assign it.  Just keep it standard for everyone.  The AS2 identifier and signing certificate are mutually exclusive.  If you don't have an AS2 identifier, it will error out.